# How can i search a CSV using another CSV list of names and return if it find a specific word using python

Tags: python, csv

So i have a CSV list of about 160 Names, i need to make a script to search each name of that 160 list on a way bigger list (1800) that contains the names and other columns of information about that name.
After it finds any matching result, it needs to find a specific word on that row and print the Initially name.

The small list contains only names.
The Bigger list contains names and several rows of information.

Basically,
Take the CSV 160name list -> Search the bigger 1800 CSV -> When it Finds the name on the bigger list, check the entire row for a specific word -> If it finds, return the name or even entire row. (no need to do anything with the rows that have no matching names)

What i have so far (bear in mind im just a person not very code savy, only have done very basic stuff) and is nowhere near completion and im pretty stuck

```py
import pandas as pd
specificlist = pd.read_csv('Small_list.csv')
General_list = pd.read_csv('Bigger_list.csv')
small_list = small_list.add_prefix('1_')
BigList = General_list.add_prefix('2_')


def compare_files(df):
    if df['1_Name'] == df['2_Name']:
        if df['2_Pet'] == 'Yes': 
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

https://prnt.sc/wrdlz0 Visual representation of what im trying.

Specifics about the scenario:
A - List of names
B- List of names, with associated addresses, DoB, Yes/No Pets (the Yes or No word answer on this column is not present on any other column) .

i want to return the name of the people on list A that have Pets

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
import pandas

names = []
with open("Small_list.csv", "r") as f:
    r = pandas.read_csv(f)
    names = list(r["name"])

with open("Bigger_list.csv", "r") as f:
    # Skip the first line
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        cur_name = line.split(",")[0]
        if cur_name in names and cur_name not in available_names:
            available_names.append(cur_name)
```

You don't really need pandas in this problem. In fact, I could remove it:

```
names = []
available_names = []

with open("Small_list.csv", "r") as f:
    # Skip the first line
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        names.append(line.strip("\n"))

with open("Bigger_list.csv", "r") as f:
    # Skip the first line
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        cur_name = line.split(",")[0]
        if cur_name in names and cur_name not in available_names:
            available_names.append(cur_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can merge the two dataframes and then select the rows with where Pets is No and select the name and pets value.

```py
import pandas as pd

names_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Anne', 'John', 'Lisa', 'Marie']})
data_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Anne', 'Kevin', 'Clio', 'Lisa', 'Raisa', 'Matt', 'John', 'Marie'],
    'Age': [23, 27, 43, 28, 32,19, 34, 21],
    'Pets': ['Yes','Yes','No','No','Yes','No','Yes','No']
})
merged_df = names_df.merge(data_df, on='Name')

print(merged_df.loc[merged_df['Pets'] == 'No'][['Name', 'Pets']])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    Name Pets
2   Lisa   No
3  Marie   No
```